# CMS Made Simple Htaccess Mod_Rewrite not working

Tags: url, content-management-system, seo

I enabled "Pretty URL's" Using Mod_Rewrite on my CMS Mad simple 1.7 site, and it seems to be working, the 301 redirects are working and most of the rewrites are working. However instead of changing the URL's to www.domain.com/page-title it is rewriting them to www.domain.com/?page=page-title

Can someone please help?!

```
# BEGIN Optional settings

# Turns off directory browsing
# not absolutely essential, but keeps people from snooping around without 
# needing empty index.html files everywhere
Options -Indexes

# Deny access to config.php
# This can be useful if php ever breaks or dies
# Use with caution, this may break other functions of CMSms that use a config.php
# file.  This may also break other programs you have running under your CMSms
# install that use config.php.  You may need to add another .htaccess file to those
# directories to specifically allow config.php.
<Files "config.php">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# Sets your 403 error document
# not absolutely essential to have, 
# or you may already have error pages defined elsewhere
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden403.shtml

# No sense advertising what we are running
ServerSignature Off

# END Optional Settings

# BEGIN CMSMS and Rewrite Rules
# Make sure you have Options FollowSymLinks
# and Allow on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# Might be needed in a subdirectory
RewriteBase /

# URL Filtering helps stop some hack attempts
#IF the URI contains a "http:"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\: [OR]
#OR if the URI contains a "["
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \[ [OR]
#OR if the URI contains a "]"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \] [OR]
#OR if the URI contains a "<script>"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
#OR script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
#OR any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L] 
# END Filtering

# CMSMS Rewriting
# Set assume mod_rewrite to true in config.php and clear CMSMS cache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|htm|html|asp|cfm|shtml|shtm)/?$ / [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# END CMSMS

# END Rewrite rules
```

Answer (score 0):

CMSMS 1.7 is a very old version - it is out of support and you should update asap.

In CMSMS docs folder you will find a worked .htaccess version

Comment: I have a custom theme, and I am worried if I update, the theme will no longer be compatible.